# How do I add an empty directory to a Git repository?

Tags: git, directory, git-add

How do I add an empty directory (that contains no files) to a Git repository?

Comment: While it's not useful, [there is a way to hack an empty (really empty) directory into your repo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600871/git-repo-contains-an-empty-directory-what-happens/11600882#11600882). It won't `checkout` with current versions of Git, however.

Answer (score 5113, accepted):

Another way to make a directory stay (almost) empty (in the repository) is to create a `.gitignore` file inside that directory that contains these four lines:

```
# Ignore everything in this directory
*
# Except this file
!.gitignore
```

Then you don't have to get the order right the way that you have to do in m104's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/180917/32453).

This also gives the benefit that files in that directory won't show up as "untracked" when you do a git status.

Making [@GreenAsJade](https://stackoverflow.com/users/554807/greenasjade)'s comment persistent:

> I think it's worth noting that this solution does precisely what the question asked for, but is not perhaps what many people looking at this question will have been looking for. This solution guarantees that the directory remains empty. It says "I truly never want files checked in here". As opposed to "I don't have any files to check in here, yet, but I need the directory here, files may be coming later".

Comment: I think the README solution proposed by @JohnMee should be used together with this one; the .gitignore file provides an explanation of what we want to keep out of version control, while the README file explains what is the purpose of the directory, which are both very important pieces of information.

Comment: @pedromanoel I write the documentation you would put in the `README` inside the `.gitignore` file (as comments).

Comment: spot the 1 difference: 1.) an empty folder, 2.) a folder with .gitignore file in it. ;-)

Comment: This is perfect for *cache* folders.

Comment: Unfortunately, this results in a non-empty directory, it has a single hidden file.

Comment: @pedorro in some cases this is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1217):

You can't.  See the [Git FAQ](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Can_I_add_empty_directories.3F).

> Currently the design of the git index
>   (staging area) only permits files to
>   be listed, and nobody competent enough
>   to make the change to allow empty
>   directories has cared enough about
>   this situation to remedy it.
>
> Directories are added automatically
>   when adding files inside them. That
>   is, directories never have to be added
>   to the repository, and are not tracked
>   on their own.
>
> You can say "`git add <dir>`" and it
>   will add files in there.
>
> If you really need a directory to
>   exist in checkouts you should create a
>   file in it. .gitignore works well for
>   this purpose; you can leave it empty,
>   or fill in the names of files you
>   expect to show up in the directory.

Comment: Should specify that it's not possible if you consider having a .gitignore *not* empty.  Also, if a directory is removed from the remote, pulling will remove the files but not the empty directories locally

Answer (score 1118):

Create an empty file called `.gitkeep` in the directory, and `git add` it.

This will be a hidden file on Unix-like systems by default but it will force Git to acknowledge the existence of the directory since it now has content.

Also note that there is nothing special about this file's name. You could have named it anything you wanted. All Git cares about is that the folder has something in it.

Comment: `.gitkeep` has not been prescribed by Git and is going to make people second guess its meaning, which will lead them to google searches, which will lead them here. The `.git` prefix convention should be reserved for files and directories that Git itself uses.

Comment: @t-mart "The `.git` prefix convention should be reserved..." Why? Does git request this reservation?

Comment: In this case a `README` or `ABOUT` file would be just as good or better. Leaving a note for the next guy, just like we all used to do it before URLs.

Comment: Doesn't work if you're writing a unit test that should test code on an empty directory...

Comment: @szablica I don't think it's confusing at all. In fact I think it's very intuitive to call it .gitkeep. Calling it .gitignore is what sounds contradictory to me. So this is just a matter of personal taste.

Comment: The reasons to use `.keep` are very good. A good balance between simple and less confusing. See the other answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/21422128/832230 If you have adopted the .gitkeep habit, run this over your repository: `git mv .gitkeep .keep`

Comment: `.emptydir` can be less confusing than `.gitkeep`.

Comment: you can create this file in windows using this command `echo>.gitkeep`

Comment: This answer is being [discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421153/73226)

Comment: @t-mart One major advantage of calling it `.gitkeep` is that developers seeing the file will instantly understand that its purpose is related to git. The fact a search might lead them here also means that they can quickly find out the intentions of the person who put it there, and clear intentions are golden in software.

Comment: More "standard": `touch .gitignore && git add .gitignore`.

Answer (score 563):

You could always put a README file in the directory with an explanation of why you want this, otherwise empty, directory in the repository.

Answer (score 481):

```
touch .placeholder
```

On Linux, this creates an empty file named `.placeholder`. For what it's worth, this name is agnostic to git, and this approach is used in various other places in the system, e.g. `/etc/cron.d/.placeholder`. Secondly, as another user has noted, the `.git` prefix convention can be reserved for files and directories that Git itself uses for configuration purposes.

Alternatively, as noted in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5305908/), **the directory can contain a descriptive [`README.md` file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655937/github-readme-and-readme-md) instead**.

Either way this requires that the presence of the file won't cause your application to break.

Comment: The reasons to use `.keep` over `.gitkeep` are very good. A good balance between simple and less confusing. Namespaces seem important and it should not be broken that `.git....` looks like git's own file namespace. Additional documentation could go the projects global readme or coding style guides or a local readme. If you have adopted the .gitkeep habit, simply find the files and rename them: `git mv .gitkeep .keep`. Embrace change! The `.gitignore` solution recommended by the git documentation seems a hacky workaround and over complicated.

Comment: On Windows, the `touch` command is part of *Git Bash* (the explorer plugin); another option is by using [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about "What is Windows Subsystem for Linux | Microsoft Learn").

Answer (score 378):

#### Why would we need empty versioned folders

First things first:

> An empty directory *cannot be part of a tree under the Git versioning system*.

It simply won't be tracked. But there are scenarios in which "versioning" empty directories can be meaningful, for example:

- scaffolding a **predefined folder structure**, making it available to every user/contributor of the repository; or, as a specialized case of the above, creating a folder for **temporary files**, such as a `cache/` or `logs/` directories, where we want to provide the folder but `.gitignore` its contents
- related to the above, some projects *won't work without some folders* (which is often a hint of a poorly designed project, but it's a frequent real-world scenario and maybe there could be, say, permission problems to be addressed).

#### Some suggested workarounds

Many users suggest:

1. Placing a `README` file or another file with some content in order to make the directory non-empty, or
2. Creating a `.gitignore` file with a sort of "reverse logic" (i.e. to include all the files) which, at the end, serves the same purpose of approach #1.

While *both solutions surely work* I find them inconsistent with a meaningful approach to Git versioning.

- Why are you supposed to put bogus files or READMEs that maybe you don't really want in your project?
- Why use `.gitignore` to do a thing (*keeping* files) that is the very opposite of what it's meant for (*excluding* files), even though it is possible?

#### .gitkeep approach

Use an *empty* file called `.gitkeep` in order to force the presence of the folder in the versioning system.

Although it may seem not such a big difference:

- You use a file that has the *single* purpose of keeping the folder. You don't put there any info you don't want to put.

  For instance, you should use READMEs as, well, READMEs with useful information, not as an excuse to keep the folder.

  Separation of concerns is always a good thing, and you can still add a `.gitignore` to ignore unwanted files.
- Naming it `.gitkeep` makes it very clear and straightforward from the filename itself (and also *to other developers*, which is good for a shared project and one of the core purposes of a Git repository) that this file is

  - A file unrelated to the code (because of the leading dot and the name)
  - A file clearly related to Git
  - Its purpose (**keep**) is clearly stated and consistent and semantically opposed in its meaning to **ignore**

#### Adoption

I've seen the `.gitkeep` approach adopted by very important frameworks like [Laravel](https://laravel.com/), [Angular-CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli).

Answer (score 141):

As described in other answers, Git is unable to represent empty directories in its staging area. (See the [Git FAQ](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Can_I_add_empty_directories.3F).) However, if, for your purposes, a directory is empty enough if it contains a `.gitignore` file only, then you can create `.gitignore` files in empty directories only via:

```
find . -type d -empty -exec touch {}/.gitignore \;
```

Comment: You may want to ignore the .git directory:  

``find . -name .git -prune -o -type d -empty -exec touch {}/.gitignore \;``

Comment: A simpler variation for most situations is `find * -type d -empty -exec touch {}/.gitignore \;`

Comment: Since OS X creates a .DS_Store file in almost every directoy, this does not work there. The only (DANGEROUS!) workaround i found, was to delete all the .DS_Store files first via `find . -name .DS_Store -exec rm {} \;` and then use the preferred variant from this answer.
Be sure to only execute this in the correct folder!

Comment: Does anyone know a way to do this in Windows from the command line? I've seen some solutions here in Ruby and Python, but I'd like a barebones solution if it can be managed.

Comment: @zerweck You should have `.DS_Store` in `.gitignore`. See [this link](http://devoh.com/blog/2013/01/global-gitignore) on to set it up.

Comment: @akhan Adding something to `.gitignore` has no influence on the `-empty` flag of the `find` command. My comment is about removing the `.DS_Store` files in a directory tree, so the `-empty` flag can be applied.

Comment: what about **find . -type d -empty -exec echo mkdir -p {} \; > make_empty_dirs.sh** 
and then commit make_empty_dirs.sh ?

Answer (score 80):

Andy Lester is right, but if your directory just needs to be empty, and not *empty* empty, you can put an empty `.gitignore` file in there as a workaround.

As an aside, this is an implementation issue, not a fundamental Git storage design problem. As has been mentioned many times on the Git mailing list, the reason that this has not been implemented is that no one has cared enough to submit a patch for it, not that it couldn’t or shouldn’t be done.

Answer (score 43):

Add a *.gitkeep* file inside the empty directory and commit it.

```
touch .gitkeep
```

.gitkeep is a hidden file, to list it in linux run command

```
ll -a
```

Comment: Do you have a reference for "It is the standard followed by Git"? I don't think it is. I think Git doesn't care how the file is named.

Answer (score 42):

TL;DR: slap a file in the directory and it will be tracked by git. (seriously. that is the official workaround)

But I recommend instead: let a build script or deploy script create the directory on site.

---

The official way:

Git does not track empty directories. See the [official Git FAQ](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Can_I_add_empty_directories.3F) for more detail. The suggested workaround is to put a `.gitignore` file in the empty directory. With the file in place the directory is no longer empty and will be tracked by git.

I do not like that workaround. The file `.gitignore` is meant to ignore things. Here it is used for the opposite: to keep something.

A common workaround (to the workaround) is to name the file `.gitkeep`. This at least conveys the intention in the filename. Also it seems to be a consensus among some projects. Git itself does not care what the file is named. It just cares if the directory is empty or not.

There is a problem shared by both `.gitkeep` and `.gitignore`: the file is hidden by unix convention. Some tools like `ls` or `cp dir/*` will pretend the file does not exists and behave as if the directory is empty. Other tools like `find -empty` will not. Newbie unix users might get stumped on this. Seasoned unix users will deduce that there are hidden files and check for them. Regardless; this is an avoidable annoyance.

Side note: a simple solution to the "hidden file problematic" is to name the file `gitkeep` (without the leading dot). We can take this one step further and name the file `README`. Then, in the file, explain why the directory needs to be empty and be tracked in git. That way other developers (and future you) can read up why things are the way they are.

Summary: slap a file in the directory and now the (formerly empty) directory is tracked by git.

Potential Problem: the directory is no longer empty.

The assumption is that you need the empty directory because you are collecting files in it to process later. But now you not only have the files you want but also one rogue `.gitignore` or `gitkeep` or what have you. This might complicate simple bash constructs like `for file in dirname/*` because you need to exclude or special case the extra file.

Git does not want to track empty directories. By trying to make git track the empty directory you sacrifice the very thing you were trying to preserve: the empty directory.

Also: spurious "empty" directories in the project directory are problems-to-be. A new developer, or future you, will stumble upon the empty directory and wonder why it needs to be there. You might delete the directory. You might put other files in it. You might even create a second workflow which also uses the empty directory. Then some time in the future it happens that both workflows using the empty directory run simultaneously and all scripts fail because the files make no sense and both teams wonder where the other files have come from.

---

My recommendation: let a build script or deploy script create the directory on site.

Lets take a few steps back. To before you asked how to make git track an empty directory.

The situation you had then was likely the following: you have a tool that needs an empty directory to work. You want to deploy/distribute this tool and you want the empty directory to also be deployed. Problem: git does not track empty directories.

Now instead of trying to get git to track empty directories lets explore the other options. Maybe (hopefully) you have a deploy script. Let the deploy script create the directory after git clone. Or you have a build script. Let the build script create the directory after compiling. Or maybe even modify the tool itself to check for and create the directory before use.

If the tool is meant to be used by humans in diverse environments then I would let the tool itself check and create the directories. If you cannot modify the tool, or the tool is used in a highly automatized manner (docker container deploy, work, destroy), then the deploy script would be good place to create the directories.

I think this is the more sensible approach to the problem. Build scripts and deploy scripts are meant to prepare things to run the program. Your tool requires an empty directory. So use those scripts to create the empty directory.

Bonus: the directory is guaranteed to be truly empty when about to be used. Also other developers (and future you) will not stumble upon an "empty" directory in the repository and wonder why it needs to be there.

TL;DR: let the build script or the deploy script create the empty directory on site. or let the tool itself check for and create the directory before use.

---

The following commands might help you if you inherited a project containing empty or "empty" directories.

To list every empty directory:

```
find -type d -empty
```

Same but avoid looking in the `.git` directory:

```
find -name .git -prune -o -type d -empty -print
```

To list every directory containing a file named `.gitkeep`:

```
find -type f -name .gitkeep
```

To list every directory and the number of files it contains:

```
find -type f -printf "%h\n" | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

Now you can examine all directories containing exactly one file and check if it is a "git keep" file. Note this command does not list directories that are truly empty.

---

Answer (score 34):

**WARNING: This tweak is not truly working as it turns out.** Sorry for the inconvenience.

**Original post below:**

I found a solution while playing with Git internals!

1. Suppose you are in your repository.
2. Create your empty directory:

   ```
   $ mkdir path/to/empty-folder
   ```
3. Add it to the index using a plumbing command and the empty tree [SHA-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1):

   ```
   $ git update-index --index-info
   040000 tree 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904    path/to/empty-folder
   ```

   Type the command and then enter the second line. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to terminate your input.
   Note: the format is *mode* [SPACE] *type* [SPACE] SHA-1hash **[TAB]** path (the tab is important, the answer formatting does not preserve it).
4. That's it! Your empty folder is in your index. All you have to do is commit.

This solution is short and apparently works fine (**see the EDIT!**), but it is not that easy to remember...

The empty tree SHA-1 can be found by creating a new empty Git repository, `cd` into it and issue `git write-tree`, which outputs the empty tree SHA-1.

**EDIT:**

I've been using this solution since I found it. It appears to work exactly the same way as creating a submodule, except that no module is defined anywhere.
This leads to errors when issuing `git submodule init|update`.
The problem is that `git update-index` rewrites the `040000 tree` part into `160000 commit`.

Moreover, any file placed under that path won't ever be noticed by Git, as it thinks they belong to some other repository. This is nasty as it can easily be overlooked!

However, if you don't already (and won't) use any Git submodules in your repository, and the "empty" folder will remain empty or if you want Git to know of its existence and ignore its content, you can go with this tweak. Going the usual way with submodules takes more steps that this tweak.

Comment: After putting the empty folder into the index and committing, is it then possible to `git svn dcommit` it with the desired result?

Comment: It's unlikely that this tweak will work with any other tool. Like stated in the warning and the edit, I discourage using it unless in a quite restricted case.

Comment: I've created a better solution based on this that doesn't have these drawbacks: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58543445/277882

Answer (score 32):

Let's say you need an empty directory named *tmp* :

```
$ mkdir tmp
$ touch tmp/.gitignore
$ git add tmp
$ echo '*' > tmp/.gitignore
$ git commit -m 'Empty directory' tmp
```

In other words, you need to add the .gitignore file to the index before you can tell Git to ignore it (and everything else in the empty directory).

Comment: Two things:
You could just "echo '*' > tmp/.gitignore" instead of touching, and "git commit -m" does not commit changes done after you've added the files to the index.

Comment: `touch file; echo bla > file` gives `file: File exists` here; in that case it's safest to use `rm file; touch file; echo something >> file` (and probably many other solutions ;-))

Comment: If you just do `echo bla > file` you will not get `file: File exists` because `>` will overwrite the file if it's already there or create a new one if it doesn't exist.

Comment: `/bin/sh` cultural assumption!* If "here" is `csh` and the variable `noclobber` is set, you will indeed get `file: File exists`. If someone says "I get this", don't assume they're an idiot and reply "No you don't". * http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?AmericanCulturalAssumption

Comment: @clacke If someone decides to use a different shell than everyone else, they should state that expressly if they are encountering problems. Unlike with nationality, everyone has their free choice of shell.

Comment: @SeldomNeedy Maybe they are looking for help because they don't even know they are using a different shell than everybody else.

Answer (score 32):

The [Ruby on Rails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails) log folder creation way:

```
mkdir log && touch log/.gitkeep && git add log/.gitkeep
```

Now the log directory will be included in the tree. It is super-useful when deploying, so you won't have to write a routine to make log directories.

The logfiles can be kept out by issuing,

```
echo log/dev.log >> .gitignore
```

but you probably knew that.

Comment: What does that have to do with Ruby on Rails?

Comment: @QuolonelQuestions https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/test/migrations/empty/.gitkeep

Comment: It has now been renamed to `.keep` https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activerecord/test/migrations/empty/.keep

Answer (score 24):

I like the answers [by Artur79](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-do-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository/8418403#8418403) [and mjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-do-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository/5871742#5871742), so I've been using a combination of both and made it a standard for our projects.

```
find . -type d -empty -exec touch {}/.gitkeep \;
```

However, only a handful of our developers work on Mac or Linux. A lot work on Windows, and I could not find an equivalent simple one-liner to accomplish the same there. Some were lucky enough to have [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/) installed for other reasons, but prescribing Cygwin just for this seemed overkill.

So, since most of our developers already have [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) installed, the first thing I thought of was to put together an Ant build file to accomplish this independently of the platform. This can still be found [here](https://github.com/mig82/gitkeep)

**However**, it would be better to make this into a small utility command, so I recreated it using Python and published it to the PyPI [here](https://pypi.org/project/gitkeep2/). You can install it by simply running:

```
pip3 install gitkeep2
```

It will allow you to create and remove `.gitkeep` files recursively, and it will also allow you to add messages to them for your peers to understand why those directories are important. This last bit is bonus. I thought it would be nice if the `.gitkeep` files could be self-documenting.

```
$ gitkeep --help
Usage: gitkeep [OPTIONS] PATH

  Add a .gitkeep file to a directory in order to push them into a Git repo
  even if they're empty.

  Read more about why this is necessary at: https://git.wiki.kernel.org/inde
  x.php/Git_FAQ#Can_I_add_empty_directories.3F

Options:
  -r, --recursive     Add or remove the .gitkeep files recursively for all
                      sub-directories in the specified path.
  -l, --let-go        Remove the .gitkeep files from the specified path.
  -e, --empty         Create empty .gitkeep files. This will ignore any
                      message provided
  -m, --message TEXT  A message to be included in the .gitkeep file, ideally
                      used to explain why it's important to push the specified
                      directory to source control even if it's empty.
  -v, --verbose       Print out everything.
  --help              Show this message and exit.
```

Comment: for what it's worth, a windows powershell one-liner could be `ls -r -dir | ?{$_.getFileSystemInfos().Count -eq 0} | %{ni -p $_.FullName -n .gitkeep}`

Answer (score 22):

Maybe adding an empty directory seems like it would be the *path of least resistance* because you have scripts that expect that directory to exist (maybe because it is a target for generated binaries).  Another approach would be to **modify your scripts to create the directory as needed**.

```
mkdir --parents .generated/bin ## create a folder for storing generated binaries
mv myprogram1 myprogram2 .generated/bin ## populate the directory as needed
```

In this example, you might check in a (broken) symbolic link to the directory so that you can access it without the ".generated" prefix (but this is optional).

```
ln -sf .generated/bin bin
git add bin
```

When you want to clean up your source tree you can just:

```
rm -rf .generated ## this should be in a "clean" script or in a makefile
```

If you take the oft-suggested approach of checking in an almost-empty folder, you have the minor complexity of deleting the contents without also deleting the ".gitignore" file.

You can ignore all of your generated files by adding the following to your root .gitignore:

```
.generated
```

Comment: Note: The symbolic link that I suggested is "broken" in a clean checkout because the `.generated` directory does not initially exist.  It will no longer be broken once you do your build.

Comment: I agree in some cases this is a very good idea, but in others (such as distributing a project where you have an otherwise empty skeleton with folders such as models/ and views/ ) you would want the user to have these directories at hand rather than manually having to read read the docs, and it could be a bit much to expect them to run some sort of installation script after cloning the repo. I think this answer in combination with @john-mee's README answer should cover most if not all cases.

Answer (score 17):

This solution worked for me.

#### 1. Add a `.gitignore` file to your empty directory:

```
*
*/
!.gitignore
```

- `*` ignore all files in the folder
- `*/` Ignore subdirectories
- `!.gitignore` include the .gitignore file

#### 2. Then remove your cache, stage your files, commit and push:

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add . // or git stage .
git commit -m ".gitignore fix"
git push
```

Answer (score 16):

You can't and unfortunately will never be able to. This is a decision made by Linus Torvald himself. He knows what's good for us.

There is a rant out there somewhere I read once.

I found *[Re: Empty directories..](http://markmail.org/message/4eqjxx73opiswfis)*, but maybe there is another one.

You have to live with the workarounds...unfortunately.

Comment: I know you posted this as an example of a bad argument, but I appreciate the link because it's actually a well-reasoned argument against tracking directories. ;-)

Comment: This answer seems to be inconsistent, since in the next post on the referenced thread, Linus Torvald says he expects that they will need to add directory tracking: http://markmail.org/message/libip4vpvvxhyqbl .  In fact, he says he "would welcome patches that [add support for tracking empty directories]"

Comment: Patrick, he also uses the word "idiotic" there. I suspect his wording adresses the people here in this thread and so I assume he will not implement something "idiotic" into Git by himself.

Answer (score 15):

I've been facing the issue with empty directories, too. The problem with using placeholder files is that you need to create them, and delete them, if they are not necessary anymore (because later on there were added sub-directories or files. With big source trees managing these placeholder files can be cumbersome and error prone.

This is why I decided to write an open source tool which can manage the creation/deletion of such placeholder files automatically. It is written for .NET platform and runs under Mono (.NET for Linux) and Windows.

Just have a look at: http://code.google.com/p/markemptydirs

Answer (score 13):

When you add a `.gitignore` file, if you are going to put any amount of content in it (that you want Git to ignore) you might want to add a single line with just an asterisk `*` to make sure you don't add the ignored content accidentally.

Answer (score 13):

Reading [ofavre's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8944077/277882) and [stanislav-bashkyrtsev's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27635349/277882) using broken Git submodule references to create the Git directories, I'm surprised that nobody has suggested yet this simple amendment of the idea to make the whole thing sane and safe:

Rather than *hacking a fake submodule into Git*, just **add an empty real one**.

#### Enter: https://gitlab.com/empty-repo/empty.git

A Git repository with exactly one commit:

```
commit e84d7b81f0033399e325b8037ed2b801a5c994e0
Author: Nobody <none>
Date: Thu Jan 1 00:00:00 1970 +0000
```

No message, no committed files.

#### Usage

To add an empty directory to you GIT repo:

```
git submodule add https://gitlab.com/empty-repo/empty.git path/to/dir
```

To convert all existing empty directories to submodules:

```
find . -type d -empty -delete -exec git submodule add -f https://gitlab.com/empty-repo/empty.git \{\} \;
```

Git will store the latest commit hash when creating the submodule reference, so you don't have to worry about me (or GitLab) using this to inject malicious files. Unfortunately I have not found any way to force which commit ID is used during checkout, so you'll have to manually check that the reference commit ID is `e84d7b81f0033399e325b8037ed2b801a5c994e0` using `git submodule status` after adding the repo.

Still not a native solution, but the best we probably can have without somebody getting their hands *really*, *really* dirty in the GIT codebase.

#### Appendix: Recreating this commit

You should be able to recreate this exact commit using (in an empty directory):

```
# Initialize new GIT repository
git init

# Set author data (don't set it as part of the `git commit` command or your default data will be stored as “commit author”)
git config --local user.name "Nobody"
git config --local user.email "none"

# Set both the commit and the author date to the start of the Unix epoch (this cannot be done using `git commit` directly)
export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="Thu Jan 1 00:00:00 1970 +0000"
export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="Thu Jan 1 00:00:00 1970 +0000"

# Add root commit
git commit --allow-empty --allow-empty-message --no-edit
```

Creating reproducible Git commits is surprisingly hard…

Comment: I've gone the path of getting really dirty in the git codebase in 2012: https://github.com/git/git/compare/master...ofavre:git:permdir. Sorry I don't remember the state of this project. I'm pretty sure that, besides being non standard, probably never accepted upstream because they are (were) really into tracking _content_, there may have been a few bugs left. The way basically it worked in the CLI was `git add folder/` with the trailing `/` adds a permanent directory.

Answer (score 11):

There's no way to get Git to track directories, so the only solution is to add a placeholder file within the directory that you want Git to track.

The file can be named and contain anything you want, but most people use an empty file named `.gitkeep` (although some people prefer the VCS-agnostic `.keep`).

The prefixed `.` marks it as a hidden file.

Another idea would be to add a `README` file explaining what the directory will be used for.

Answer (score 10):

A [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell) version:

> Find all the empty folders in the directory
>
> Add a empty .gitkeep file in there

```
Get-ChildItem 'Path to your Folder' -Recurse -Directory | Where-Object {[System.IO.Directory]::GetFileSystemEntries($_.FullName).Count -eq 0} | ForEach-Object { New-Item ($_.FullName + "\.gitkeep") -ItemType file}
```

Comment: also, ```ni -p $_.FullName -n .gitignore -v "*`r`n!.gitignore"```

Answer (score 9):

As mentioned it's not possible to add empty directories, but here is a one liner that adds empty .gitignore files to all directories.

`ruby -e 'require "fileutils" ; Dir.glob(["target_directory","target_directory/**"]).each { |f| FileUtils.touch(File.join(f, ".gitignore")) if File.directory?(f) }'`

I have stuck this in a Rakefile for easy access.

Comment: I'd rather use `find . -type d -empty -print0 | xargs --null bash -c 'for a; do { echo "*"; echo "!.gitignore"; } >>"$a/.gitignore"; done' --`

Answer (score 9):

[The solution of Jamie Flournoy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/932982/456814) works great. Here is a bit enhanced version to keep the `.htaccess` :

```
# Ignore everything in this directory
*
# Except this file
!.gitignore
!.htaccess
```

With this solution you are able to commit a empty folder, for example `/log`, `/tmp` or `/cache` and the folder will stay empty.

Comment: He wants to keep a empty directory and not a file.

Comment: And i have mentioned that it will keep the .htaccess, too. Example: if a software has a directory for log-files (like oxid eshop) that should not be accesible via web, there is a .htaccess in the directory. If you put the above mentioned .gitignore in the folder, the .htaccess will not be comitted and the folder will be accessible via web.

Comment: If you have a .htaccess file that's under version control, then you already have the directory containing it under version control. Thus, the problem is already solved - the .gitignore file becomes irrelevant.

Comment: @Wallacoloo Related to the question you're right, nevertheless the file is useful, I'll use it for an upload-directory like that where files shall be protected by .htaccess. Contrary to Romans explanation the .htaccess-file will be committed as it's excluded by the ignore-rule. [old thread, I know]

Answer (score 8):

I always build a function to check for my desired folder structure and build it for me within the project. This gets around this problem as the empty folders are held in Git by proxy.

```
function check_page_custom_folder_structure () {
    if (!is_dir(TEMPLATEPATH."/page-customs"))
        mkdir(TEMPLATEPATH."/page-customs");    
    if (!is_dir(TEMPLATEPATH."/page-customs/css"))
        mkdir(TEMPLATEPATH."/page-customs/css");
    if (!is_dir(TEMPLATEPATH."/page-customs/js"))
        mkdir(TEMPLATEPATH."/page-customs/js");
}
```

This is in PHP, but I am sure most languages support the same functionality, and because the creation of the folders is taken care of by the application, the folders will always be there.

Comment: Just so we're all on the same page, I do not do this anymore. It's a waste of time. The `.gitkeep` convention is a much better practise.

Comment: I can't see how this can be a waste of time.
When your TEMPLATEPATH is obviously dynamic you can't use the .gitkeep solution.

And even with a nondynamic folder structure you should add some more stuff instead of removing the very good solution of checking directories e.g. check for permissions and chmod the files. Adding a way to mark directories inside a global .gitignore would be perfect for me. Something like #keep /path/to/dir

Answer (score 8):

Here is a hack, but it's funny that it works (Git 2.2.1). Similar to what @Teka suggested, but easier to remember:

- Add a submodule to any repository (`git submodule add path_to_repo`)
- This will add a folder and a file `.submodules`. Commit a change.
- Delete `.submodules` file and commit the change.

Now, you have a directory that gets created when commit is checked out. An interesting thing though is that if you look at the content of tree object of this file you'll get:

> fatal: Not a valid object name
>   b64338b90b4209263b50244d18278c0999867193

I wouldn't encourage to use it though since it may stop working in the future versions of Git. Which may leave your repository corrupted.

Comment: This actually works but I think confuses the heck out of IntelliJ... :|

Comment: I've created a better solution based on this that doesn't have these drawbacks: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58543445/277882

Answer (score 8):

If you want to add a folder that will house a lot of transient data in multiple semantic directories, then one approach is to add something like this to your root .gitignore...

`/app/data/**/*.*
!/app/data/**/*.md`

Then you can commit descriptive README.md files (or blank files, doesn't matter, as long as you can target them uniquely like with the `*.md` in this case) in each directory to ensure that the directories all remain part of the repo but the files (with extensions) are kept ignored. LIMITATION: `.`'s are not allowed in the directory names!

You can fill up all of these directories with xml/images files or whatever and add more directories under `/app/data/` over time as the storage needs for your app develop (with the README.md files serving to burn in a description of what each storage directory is for exactly).

There is no need to further alter your `.gitignore` or decentralise by creating a new `.gitignore` for each new directory. Probably not the smartest solution but is terse gitignore-wise and always works for me. Nice and simple! ;)

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes you have to deal with bad written libraries or software, which need a "real" empty and existing directory. Putting a simple `.gitignore` or `.keep` might break them and cause a bug. The following might help in these cases, but no guarantee...

First create the needed directory:

```
mkdir empty
```

Then you add a broken symbolic link to this directory (but on any other case than the described use case above, please use a `README` with an explanation):

```
ln -s .this.directory empty/.keep
```

To ignore files in this directory, you can add it in your root `.gitignore`:

```
echo "/empty" >> .gitignore
```

To add the ignored file, use a parameter to force it:

```
git add -f empty/.keep
```

After the commit you have a broken symbolic link in your index and git creates the directory. The broken link has some advantages, since it is no regular file and points to no regular file. So it even fits to the part of the question "(that contains no files)", not by the intention but by the meaning, I guess:

```
find empty -type f
```

This commands shows an empty result, since no files are present in this directory. So most applications, which get all files in a directory usually do not see this link, at least if they do a "file exists" or a "is readable". Even some scripts will not find any files there:

```
$ php -r "var_export(glob('empty/.*'));"
array (
  0 => 'empty/.',
  1 => 'empty/..',
)
```

But I strongly recommend to use this solution only in special circumstances, a good written `README` in an empty directory is usually a better solution. (And I do not know if this works with a windows filesystem...)

Answer (score 7):

An easy way to do this is by adding a `.gitkeep` file to the directory you wish to (currently) keep empty.

See this [SOF answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7229996/1882064) for further info - which also explains why some people find the competing convention of adding a .gitignore file (as stated in many answers here) confusing.

Answer (score 5):

Adding one more option to the fray.

Assuming you would like to add a directory to `git` that, for all purposes related to `git`, should remain empty and never have it's contents tracked, a `.gitignore` as suggested numerous times here, will do the trick.

The format, as mentioned, is:

```
*
!.gitignore
```

Now, if you want a way to do this at the command line, in one fell swoop, while *inside* the directory you want to add, you can execute:

```
$ echo "*" > .gitignore && echo '!.gitignore' >> .gitignore && git add .gitignore
```

Myself, I have a shell script that I use to do this.  Name the script whatever you whish, and either add it somewhere in your include path, or reference it directly:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir=''

if [ "$1" != "" ]; then
    dir="$1/"
fi

echo "*" > $dir.gitignore && \
echo '!.gitignore' >> $dir.gitignore && \
git add $dir.gitignore
```

With this, you can either execute it from within the directory you wish to add, or reference the directory as it's first and only parameter:

```
$ ignore_dir ./some/directory
```

Another option (in response to a comment by @GreenAsJade), if you want to track an empty folder that *MAY* contain tracked files in the future, but will be empty for now, you can ommit the `*` from the `.gitignore` file, and check *that* in.  Basically, all the file is saying is "do not ignore *me*", but otherwise, the directory is empty and tracked.

Your `.gitignore` file would look like:

```
!.gitignore
```

That's it, check that in, and you have an empty, yet tracked, directory that you can track files in at some later time.

The reason I suggest keeping that one line in the file is that it gives the `.gitignore` purpose. Otherwise, some one down the line may think to remove it.  It may help if you place a comment above the line.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. This is an intentional design decision by the Git maintainers. Basically, the purpose of a Source Code Management System like Git is managing source code and empty directories aren't source code. Git is also often described as a content tracker, and again, empty directories aren't content (quite the opposite, actually), so they are not tracked.

Comment: I contest this view. **Structure** is content, and everything you **name** contributes to content.

Comment: An empty file isn't source code or content either. It's just a name. Yet Git will happily track empty files. I don't think it was an intentional design decision to make Git refuse to track empty directories. I think tracking empty directories is a feature that simply isn't needed 99% of the time, so they didn't bother to do the extra work required to make it work properly. Git can do it if someone wants the feature badly enough to implement it. I doubt the Git maintainers would be opposed to such a patch if it were done correctly.

Comment: @TobyAllen here is the updated [FAQ link](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Can_I_add_empty_directories.3F) The top answer is also what is recommended by the FAQ with more precise instructions.

Comment: It's a missing feature (and low priority), not an intentional limitation. From the Git FAQ: Currently the design of the Git index (staging area) only permits files to be listed, and **nobody competent enough to make the change to allow empty directories has cared enough about this situation to remedy it.**

Comment: Don't really agree. I can find various reasons why I want to track an empty folder. For example, I am developing a very lightweight PHP MVC framework for my projects. I have specific folders for placing models, views, etc. When I make a new site based on my framework, those folders are empty since there are no models or views by default, but I do need the folder to exist, else my framework won't work!

Answer (score 4):

Just add an empty (with no content) [.gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) file in the empty directory you want to track.

E.g., if you want to track an empty directory, `/project/content/posts`, then create a new empty file, `/project/content/posts/.gitignore`

Note: *.gitkeep* is not part of official [Git](https://git-scm.com/):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

To extend [Jamie Flournoy's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/932982/8213124) to a directory tree, you can put this *[.gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)* file in the top-level directory and `touch .keepdir` in each subdirectory that Git should track. All other files are ignored. This is useful to ensure a consistent structure for build directories.

```
# Ignore files but not directories. * matches both files and directories
# but */ matches only directories. Both match at every directory level
# at or below this one.
*
!*/

# Git doesn't track empty directories, so track .keepdir files, which also
# tracks the containing directory.
!.keepdir

# Keep this file and the explanation of how this works
!.gitignore
!Readme.md
```

Answer (score 2):

You can save this code as create_readme.php and run the [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) code from the root directory of your Git project.

```
php create_readme.php
```

It will add README files to all directories that are empty so those directories would be then added to the index.

```php
<?php
    $path = realpath('.');
    $objects = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path),       RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
    foreach($objects as $name => $object){
        if ( is_dir($name) && ! is_empty_folder($name) ){
            echo "$name\n" ;
            exec("touch ".$name."/"."README");
        }
    }

    function is_empty_folder($folder) {
        $files = opendir($folder);
        while ($file = readdir($files)) {
            if ($file != '.' && $file != '..')
                return true; // Not empty
            }
        }
?>
```

Then do

```
git commit -m "message"
git push
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes I have repositories with folders that will only ever contain files considered to be "content"—that is, they are not files that I care about being versioned, and therefore should never be committed. With Git's .gitignore file, you can ignore entire directories. But there are times when having the folder in the repo would be beneficial. Here's a excellent solution for accomplishing this need.

What I've done in the past is put a .gitignore file at the root of my repo, and then exclude the folder, like so:

```
/app/some-folder-to-exclude
/another-folder-to-exclude/*
```

However, these folders then don't become part of the repo. You could add something like a README file in there. But then you have to tell your application not to worry about processing any README files.

If your app depends on the folders being there (though empty), you can simply add a .gitignore file to the folder in question, and use it to accomplish two goals:

Tell Git there's a file in the folder, which makes Git add it to the repo.
Tell Git to ignore the contents of this folder, minus this file itself.
Here is the .gitignore file to put inside your empty directories:

```
*
!.gitignore
```

The first line (*) tells Git to ignore everything in this directory. The second line tells Git not to ignore the .gitignore file. You can stuff this file into every empty folder you want added to the repository.

Answer (score 0):

I search into this question because: I create a new directory and it contains many files. Among these files, some I want to add to Git repository and some not. But when I do "git status". It only shows:

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    ../trine/device_android/
```

It does not list the separate files in this new directory. Then I think maybe I can add this directory only and then deal with the separate files. So I google "Git add directory only".

In my situation, I found I can just add one file in the new directory that I am sure I want to add it to Git.

```
git add new_folder/some_file
```

After this, "git status" will show the status of separate files.

Answer (score -8):

Just add a `readme` or a `.gitignore` file and then delete it, but not from terminal, from the GitHub website. That will give an empty repository.

Comment: They were asking for an empty directory, not an empty repository. Also, you’ve assumed they are using GitHub when they only talked about git.